# How to create a site as site template in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I have created a project site and added some web part document libraries etc. I would like to use this as a template for all the new sites.

How do I do that?

Comment: Save Site as Template option in not available in SharePoint online, you can follow this link, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192050/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Save site as template` option in **SharePoint Online** to save your current customized site as a template then use this template as a custom template for the future sites.

[image]

**But there are some cases where you will missing this option as the following:**

- Your Current site is Publishing Site.
- Your Current site is Community Site.
- Your Current site is Team Site but the `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature is currently enabled.
- Your Current site is Team Site but the `Community Site feature` is currently enabled.
- The current site has ever had Publishing or Community Site features enabled can’t be saved as a template.

> **Note:** any workaround to `savs site as a template` for the above cases is not supported and not working properly!!

- If you disabled Custom Script capabilities in Center Admin, it will lead to missing  Save Site As Template option.

  - To allow `Custom Script`, go to SharePoint Admin Center > Settings > Custom Script > Check:

    - Allow users to run custom script on personal sites.
    - Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites

> **Note:** Changes to the above settings might take up 24 hours to take effect!

---

**For more details check**

- [Missing Save Site As Template in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)
- [Save site as template" option isn't available in SharePoint Online in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2492356/-save-site-as-template-option-isn-t-available-in-sharepoint-online-in)

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed replay, what about "Project site" I have created a project site and tried to save it as a template. it does not have "SharePoint server Publishing" or "Community Site features" enabled. But i remember adding "Site Pages and Wiki Site pages activated" and i had activated Custom Script "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites" Turned on. As you had mentioned it may take up to 24 hours . i will update you soon.

Comment: You are welcome :), Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi M.Qassas, I had to deactivate SharePoint server publishing infrastructure from the site collection feature and SharePoint publishing from the same level site features to get it working.