# Sharepoint Online - Site Collection rollback a few days

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, restore, sub-site

I did something wrong and just want to rollback a few days.

Is it possible to restore a site in SharePoint Online?

**P.S.** not the top site, a departmental subsite

Comment: Thank you everyone who posted answers. All is well. Microsoft restore the site collection. However, I need to come up with a good back up plan. The site stayed broken for a week while I was waiting for the restoration and it wasn't ideal! I am trying to figure out how to make  a back up for SharePoint Online site collection.

Answer (score 2):

**As a short answer,** No, you can't

---

**The detailed Answer >>**

**First,** You can't perform a backup and restore in SharePoint Online as we do in SharePoint On-Prem!

So If you need to take a backup, you should

- Make [service request to the O365 support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Contact-Office-365-for-business-support-Admin-Help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b)
- Or use a 3rd party tool.

**Secondly,** In SharePoint online, the OOTB option that might help you to rollback your changes is **Saving site as template** that only available on the publishing site,

**So** If you didn't save your site as a template before performing your new modifications, you will not be able to rollback your changes.

> **By the way,** the purpose of `Saving site as template` is not to backup and restore a site, the main purpose is to create a template that can be used for multiple sites with the same features that will accelerate the site customization process!
>
> So you can't overwrite the same site with this saved template, you should create a new site from the saved template. so it's not considered a proper solution.
>
> For more details about save site as template option,  check
>
> - [Save site as template in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192050/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-online)
> - [SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I contacted Microsoft and they are working on it now.

Comment: @Hatter Please don't forget to accept the correct answer in case it helped you

Answer (score 0):

**Restore a Deleted Site**

(SharePoint 2013)

---

Use the following steps to restore a deleted site from the second-stage Recycle Bin.

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure has the **site collection administrator** permission.
2. In **Central Administration**, click **Site Actions**, and then click **Site Settings**.
3. In the **Site Settings** section, click **Recycle Bin**.
4. On the **Recycle Bin** page, select the **check box for the deleted site** that you want to restore.
5. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge Office 365's instances of SharePoint do not allow custom backup/restore procedures.

If it has a strong business impact , you can raise a support ticket to Microsoft , on more thing is that the time of the restore should be chosen based on the last known time in which the item(s) was in the desired state and no more than 14 days in the past.

More information please refer to : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomvan/2015/12/23/restore-options-in-sharepoint-online-must-read/

Comment: Thank you. I contacted Microsoft and they are working on it now.